# Glob works on local machine fails to detect files in remote

Tags: windows, perl, glob

I'm using glob to get a list of all the files inside the target directory. This works on my laptop but not on my server.

Here's my code:

```
my $dir = "c:/MyTargetDir";    
@files = glob "$dir/*.*";
print $dir . "\n";
print $#files;
```

Results:

```
c:/MyTargetDir
0
```

I've already set the folder security settings to allow everyone's modification but it's still not working. What might be causing this?

UPDATE:

OK legit another case of noob assumptions here. Thought `$#files` would show the amount of object inside the array but it actually shows one less of the actual amount of objects, meant for the `for (0..$#files)` loop. The problem actually lies elsewhere but I assumed wrongly. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: still 0 on the @files count. Is there an alternative to glob that doesn't require installing new modules?

Comment: Do you have permissions? `dir C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyTargetDir` from command line?

Comment: @mpapec yes I can see the file inside using the `dir` command

Comment: note that `$#files` is the size minus one. So there *is* one element inside `@files`. If it were empty, we'd expect `-1`. Could you `print "$_\n" for @files` as well?

Comment: i should go cry in a corner for not knowing about the `$#array` being equal to the size minus 1. Thanks for that. I figured where the problem is now.

Answer (score 3):

If `MyTargetDir` actually contains spaces, you need to [use `bsd_glob` instead](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html), which treats spaces as part of the file name.

```
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';
@files = bsd_glob "$dir/*.*";
```

Otherwise, there is seemingly no problem with your code, and you may still have a permissions issue.  You should check `$!` to see if you are getting an error.

If you want to simply get all files in a directory, [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) might be a better solution

Comment: no spaces. the whole path is "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyTargetDir"

Comment: about 20 characters with underscore instead of spaces

Comment: how do i use `$!`? i'm still new to perl so i only know the basics